# Parse XML to String where XML is returned from the server

Tags: jquery, xml

So i currently have the following code:

```
<script>
    var params = {};
    var results = '';
    params["companyID"] = <%=company.getId()%>
    $.ajax({
        url: "services/contacts/<%=ContactServices.Action.GET_CONTACT_LIST%>",
        data: params,
        complete: function(xhr) {
            results = xhr;
            console.log(results);
            var booboo = $.parseXML(results);
            console.log(booboo);
        }
    });
</script>
```

and results returns back the following responseText:

```
 "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?><Response>[Fara Hussain,
 Default Contact, Gogo Hussain, Emma Lowdon, John
 Stewart]<Success/></Response>"
```

I am currently intrested with the items that are in the brackets only:

> Fara Hussain, Default Contact, Gogo Hussain, Emma Lowdon, John Stewart

I then attempt to parse the XML. However, when i try to parse the XML, it returns null.

```
var booboo = $.parseXML(results);
console.log(booboo);
```

Any ideas how to overcome this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jqXHR is not the response from the server. You need to parse the response not the ajax object itself.

```
complete: function(xhr) {
        results = xhr.responseXML || xhr.responseText;
        console.log(results);
        var booboo = $.parseXML(results);
        console.log(booboo);
    }
```

---

Here's a neat trick to just get the stuff in the brackets:

```js
var results = "<Response>[Mubean Hussain, Default Contact, Mubean Hussain, Emma Harding, John Stewart]<Success/></Response>";
var text = $("<div>").html(results).text();
// text will now contain just the stuff in the brackets
console.log(text);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This works by creating a dummy div that is not added to the DOM, inserting the xml as html and then getting the `textContent` of the div which ignores any markup.

Comment: This is a little better but is there a way to return back only the value within the brackets. At the moment it is showing up as following:

Comment: <Response>[Mubean fsa, Default Contact, Mubean fs, Emma da, John Stewart]<Success/></Response>